# jQuery UI Date Picker: Block off the next 3 business days

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the following code to block off all Sundays from my jQuery UI Date Picker. I'd also like to block off today and the next 3 business days from today. Anybody know how this can be done?

```
$("#pick-delivery-date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    altField: "#selected-delivery-date",
    altFormat: "DD, d MM, yy",
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 0), ''];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the minDate option, something like...

{ minDate: +3 }

Comment: That works for the next three days, but not for specific days.

Comment: Sure but beforeShowDay already handles specific days. Simple always best solution, single responsibility single change principle.

Answer (score 0):

```
var unavailableDates = ["9-5-2011","14-5-2011","15-5-2011"];

$("#pick-delivery-date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    altField: "#selected-delivery-date",
    altFormat: "DD, d MM, yy",
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
      if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) < 0) {
        return [true,"","Book Now"];
      } else {
        return [false,"","Booked Out"];
      }
    }
});
```